# Storing string then displaying it with a label box

Tags: vb.net, replace

I am trying to store the string from an input box and then display it with dashes in the `lblbox` for a hangman game for a class.

These are the tasks that I am struggling with:

- edit the program to allow a Secret Word of any length.
- the program will allow the ‘guesser’ to guess 2 times the length of the word.  As an example, the word ‘code’ will allow 8 total guesses.
- As the user guesses at letters contained in the word the program will:
  Count the number of attempts the user has completed.
  Replace the appropriate dash (-) with the correct letter, if the correct letter has been guessed.
- When all the letters have been guessed correctly all the dashes (-) should be replaced with the appropriate letters, and a message box should appear stating “Great Job playing Hangman.!”
- If the user is unable to guess the correct word in the amount of guesses allowed; the dashes (-) should be replaced with GAME OVER! and a message box should appear stating “Sorry the correct word was________”
- 2 bonus points will be awarded for displaying all incorrect letters guess in a 3rd label control.
- 4 more additional bonus points will be awarded for not allowing, or counting a user who guesses the same incorrect letter twice.

Here is my code:

```
Dim strSecretWord As String
Dim strLetterGuessed As String
Dim blnDashReplaced As Boolean
Dim intNumberOfRemainingGuesses As Integer = 10
Dim intNumofGuesses As Integer = 0

lblSecretWord.Text = ""
lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""

'start game and have 1st user input a 5 letter word that 2nd player needs to guess
strSecretWord = InputBox("Please input a 5 letter word for user to guess:", "Please input secret word.").ToUpper


'displays five dashes for the secret word
lblSecretWord.Text = lblSecretWord.Text & "-----"


'guessing player recieves inputbox to make letter guesses 
MessageBox.Show("The length of the word is 5 letters, you will be given 10 guesses", "10 guesses", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
MessageBox.Show("Player who gets to guess, BE READY!", "Good Luck Guessing", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

'Counts number of attempts player gets (10) and replaces dashes with guessed letter if correct
'If guessed letter was incorrect, user loses a turn
For intNumberofGuesses = 1 To 10
    strLetterGuessed = InputBox("Please guess a letter:", "Letter Guess").ToUpper


    'Uses an IntIndex counter of 0 to 4 to execute 5 times (5 dashes)
    'Also uses the value of intIndex to check each of the 5 locations of the strSecretWord
    For intIndex As Integer = 0 To 4

        'if the user has guessed a correct letter then remove a dash and insert the correct letter guessed
        If strSecretWord.Substring(intIndex, 1) = strLetterGuessed Then
            lblSecretWord.Text = lblSecretWord.Text.Remove(intIndex, 1)
            lblSecretWord.Text = lblSecretWord.Text.Insert(intIndex, strLetterGuessed)
            blnDashReplaced = True
        End If
    Next intIndex

    'If the user guessed a correct letter on their last guess the blnDashReplaced is set and the true condition of the If statement is executed
    If blnDashReplaced = True Then

        'if there are no more dashes, and the game has been solved.
        If lblSecretWord.Text.Contains("-") = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Great Job playign Hangman!", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
            lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        Else
            blnDashReplaced = False
        End If
    Else

    End If
    lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = intNumberofGuesses
    intNumberOfRemainingGuesses = intNumberOfRemainingGuesses - 1
    lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = intNumberOfRemainingGuesses

Next
lblSecretWord.Text = "GAME OVER!"
MessageBox.Show("Better luck next time. Sorry the correct word was " & strSecretWord & ".", "You Lost", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
```

Comment: OK - you say you are struggling. In this particular instance, what specific item  are you struggling with? What is not happening as expected? What is happening that is unexpected? What is the problem that *we* can help you with?

Comment: the first part is getting  the word the user types in as dashes, the code is currently wrote for a word that is five letters long. so lbdisplay="----" is not valid.

Comment: I tried using this code  return str.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/g , '-'); but the program barks at me. How do I take the word the user enters, lets say the word is cupcake. to display in the lbl -------   (have 7 dashes)

Comment: So you want to know the **length** of the input string and create a string of dashes the same **length**? VB.net has some inbuilt commands to do that. And then, some of the inbuilt functions will allow you to adjust the **mid**dle of a stirng (or better yet, a **substring**) to replace the "-" with the appropriate letter as they guess correctly.

Comment: yes. I have looked over my class tutorials and they explain how to replace parts of a string xyz to 123   or trim the ends of a string. but nothing to each charter that the user  inputs. I looked to see if there was a replaceall but did not see anything

Comment: Instead of replacing word for a word, replace everything with something else.

Comment: Check New String(). Also, edit your question to be shorter and clearer on what the actual problem is, what happens and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I added a list box to keep the guessed letters. Other comments and explanations in line.

```
Public Class Form3
    'Move this to a class level variable so it can be seen by
    'all the methods in the class
    Private strSecretWord As String

    Private Sub btnStartGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartGame.Click
        Dim strLetterGuessed As String
        Dim blnDashReplaced As Boolean
        Dim intNumberOfRemainingGuesses As Integer
        Dim intNumofGuesses As Integer = 0

        'Display correct number of dashes
        Dim numberOfDashes As Integer = strSecretWord.Length
        'Create a string with correct number of dashes
        'This uses and overload of the String constructor that takes a Char and an integer
        'as arguments and returns a string with that character repeated that number
        'of times. The lower case c following "-" indicates that - is a Char.
        Dim TotalNumofGuesses = numberOfDashes * 2
        lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = TotalNumofGuesses.ToString
        intNumberOfRemainingGuesses = TotalNumofGuesses
        Dim dashString As String = New String("-"c, numberOfDashes)
        'displays the dashes
        lblSecretWord.Text = dashString

        'guessing player recieves inputbox to make letter guesses 
        'You can use an Interpolated string to display variables in line surrounded by { }.
        'In older versions of VB String.Format() will yield the same result.
        MessageBox.Show($"The length of the word is {numberOfDashes} letters, you will be given {TotalNumofGuesses} guesses", $"{TotalNumofGuesses} guesses", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        MessageBox.Show("Player who gets to guess, BE READY!", "Good Luck Guessing", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        'Counts number of attempts player gets and replaces dashes with guessed letter if correct
        'If guessed letter was incorrect, user loses a turn
        For counter = 1 To TotalNumofGuesses
            strLetterGuessed = InputBox("Please guess a letter:", "Letter Guess").ToUpper
            'If lstLettersGuessed.Contains(strLetterGuessed) Then
            If lbxLettersGuessed.Items.Contains(strLetterGuessed) Then
                MessageBox.Show($"{strLetterGuessed} has already been guessed.", "Try Again")
                'need to do this so they are not cheated out of a guess
                TotalNumofGuesses += 1
                Continue For 'Moves to the next iteration of the For
            End If
            lbxLettersGuessed.Items.Add(strLetterGuessed)
            'lstLettersGuessed.Add(strLetterGuessed)
            'Uses an IntIndex counter of 0 to 4 to execute 5 times (5 dashes)
            'Also uses the value of intIndex to check each of the 5 locations of the strSecretWord
            For intIndex As Integer = 0 To numberOfDashes - 1
                'if the user has guessed a correct letter then remove a dash and insert the correct letter guessed
                If strSecretWord.Substring(intIndex, 1) = strLetterGuessed Then
                    lblSecretWord.Text = lblSecretWord.Text.Remove(intIndex, 1)
                    lblSecretWord.Text = lblSecretWord.Text.Insert(intIndex, strLetterGuessed)
                    blnDashReplaced = True
                End If
            Next intIndex

            'If the user guessed a correct letter on their last guess the blnDashReplaced is set and the true condition of the If statement is executed
            If blnDashReplaced = True Then
                'if there are no more dashes, and the game has been solved.
                If lblSecretWord.Text.Contains("-") = False Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Great Job playing Hangman!", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                    'Do this at start of game, player wants to see final score
                    'lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
                    'lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    blnDashReplaced = False
                End If
            End If
            'This is a shorter way of incrementing a variable
            intNumofGuesses += 1
            'Can't put an integer into a Text property, it needs a string
            lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = intNumofGuesses.ToString
            'This is a shorter way of decrementing a variable
            intNumberOfRemainingGuesses -= 1
            'Can't put an integer into a Text property, it needs a string
            lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = intNumberOfRemainingGuesses.ToString

        Next
        lblSecretWord.Text = "GAME OVER!"
        MessageBox.Show("Better luck next time. Sorry the correct word was " & strSecretWord & ".", "You Lost", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        'Do this at start of game
        'lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
        'lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSetUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSetUp.Click
        lblSecretWord.Text = ""
        lblNumberOfAttempts.Text = "0"
        lblRemainingNumberOfAttempts.Text = "0"
        lbxLettersGuessed.Items.Clear()
        'start game and have 1st user input a 5 letter word that 2nd player needs to guess
        strSecretWord = InputBox("Please input a word for user to guess:", "Please input secret word.").ToUpper
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: im confused on the lbxlettersguessed  i only have one display   lblDisplay   whats lbx

Comment: what am i missing here guys?   Keps giving me an error       Dim message As String = ("the length of the word is " & numberOfDashes & "and you will get" & TotalNumofGuesses & "chances")


        MessageBox.Show(message), "game details", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

Comment: lbx is the list box. It is just another control. It works easier for storing the and displaying the used letters.

Comment: I don't see 'Dim message as String` in my Answer.